# Yet another "Access denied for user" error..but I can log in directly to remote server from command line

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Java 1.7
Spring 3.1.1 with Spring-WS 2.1.1
Joda
Hibernate 3.6
MySQL 5.0.51a
Maven 3
Tomcat 7
Eclipse 3.7

Greetings all...

Just another 'Access denied for user 'foo'@'localhost' error being thrown by my webapp, but with a twist.

I run both an instance of MySQL on my (duh) local machine for development, and another on my remote server.

Both instances have a database 'mydb' and two tables with identical names and structures.

On the local instance I use root.

On the remote machine I have issued the following sequence:

```
CREATE USER 'fubar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypwd';
CREATE USER 'fubar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypwd';
CREATE USER 'fubar'@'my.remote.server.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypwd';
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO ' CREATE USER 'fubar'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypwd';               
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO ' CREATE USER 'fubar'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypwd';               
GRANT ALL ON mydb.* TO ' CREATE USER 'fubar'@'my.remote.server.com' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypwd';               
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

I've confirmed with a 'select * from mysql.db' that three new rows appear and that all the appropriate fields have 'Y' values.

On the local machine from within a Command Prompt pane I can issue:

```
mysql -u fubar -p -h my.remote.server.com ,
```

reply with the password and get connected to the remote db.

Executing my java program fails with the famous 
'Access denied for user 'fubar'@'localhost' 
when url is adjusted to point to remote server

Using the following as part of my db.properties file in my Eclipse project:

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb
hibernate.connection.username=root
hibernate.connection.password=myrootpwd
```

execution works great

execution fails with the dreaded error when using this:

```
hibernate.connection.url=jdbc:mysql://my.remote.servier.com:3306/mydb
hibernate.connection.username=fubar
hibernate.connection.password=mypwd
```

So I am stumped. How is that I can connect directly to the remote instance of MySQL server using the command line but not in my db.properties file?

TIA,

Still-learning Stev

Comment: your grant queries are totally invalid, so even if the users did get created, they wouldn't have any privs anyways.

Comment: besides, I would watch, whether the `bind-address`-option restricts access

Answer (score -1):

I got into the same issue and its the wrong password that created the whole issue...

You can use the standalone java program code in the below link to test your connection and make sure it works first...

http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/